# Validate JIRA summary for a string value

Tags: jira

I have a requirement, I need to run a validation at the create screen with following condition:
1. Tool: Jira
2. Validation Field: Summary
3. String: Test

I am using Workflow validatory, which works fine as:
Scenarion: 
Summary Field: "Test"

It fails with such scenarios as:
Summary Field: "This is a Test Case"

I am trying to find out a way out for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free [AM Utils](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/ru.andreymarkelov.atlas.plugins.utils/server/overview) plugin to add a validator with a RegExp so you can accomodate any need.

Comment: Thanks for your inputs. I applied Java compliant REGEX with "\\" and it worked.